# UI not updating when clicking on 'MaskOptionWidget"

Tags: flutter, widget, setstate, state-management

My UI is not updating with a masked preview image when i click on the **'MaskOptionWidget'** which basically triggers a gesture detector and should preview me a masked image in the alertdialog widget. When i close the alertdialog and upload an image again, then i am able to see the masked image. I dont know why its not updating instantly and showing me the masked image when i click on **'MaskOptionWidget'**.

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_unnecessary_containers, prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables, use_build_context_synchronously

import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:widget_mask/widget_mask.dart';

String? _selectedMask;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.green),
        useMaterial3: true,
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
          color: Colors.white,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
          systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
            statusBarColor: Colors.green,
            statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
            statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Add Image /  Icon'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        //backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Center(child: Text(widget.title)),
        elevation: 4,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            // Close the app when the back icon is pressed
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 350,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.grey, // Border color
                  width: 1.0, // Border width
                ),
              ),
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30), // Add left margin
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Spacer(),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                          height: 50,
                          child: Text(
                            "Upload Image",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 12),
                        Container(
                          height: 50,
                          width: 200,
                          child: TextButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              final picker = ImagePicker();
                              final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(
                                  source: ImageSource.gallery);

                              if (pickedFile != null) {
                                showDialog(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                    return AlertDialog(
                                      title: Text('Image Preview'),
                                      content: ImagePreviewDialog(
                                        pickedImagePath: pickedFile.path,
                                      ),
                                      actions: <Widget>[
                                        TextButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                          },
                                          child: Text('Close'),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  },
                                );
                              }
                            },
                            child: Text('Choose image'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MaskOptionsList extends StatelessWidget {
  const MaskOptionsList({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> maskOptions = [
      MaskOptionWidget(
          option: 'Heart',
          icon: Icons.favorite,
          maskImagePath: 'images/user_image_frame_1.png'),
      MaskOptionWidget(
          option: 'Circle',
          icon: Icons.circle,
          maskImagePath: 'images/user_image_frame_2.png'),
    ];

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: maskOptions,
    );
  }
}

class MaskOptionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String option;
  final String maskImagePath;
  final IconData icon;

  MaskOptionWidget(
      {required this.option, required this.icon, required this.maskImagePath});

  @override
  State<MaskOptionWidget> createState() => _MaskOptionWidgetState();
}

class _MaskOptionWidgetState extends State<MaskOptionWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _selectedMask = widget.maskImagePath;
          // Handle mask option selection here
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Icon(
          widget.icon,
          size: 48,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImagePreviewDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final String pickedImagePath;

  ImagePreviewDialog({required this.pickedImagePath});

  @override
  _ImagePreviewDialogState createState() => _ImagePreviewDialogState();
}

class _ImagePreviewDialogState extends State<ImagePreviewDialog> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        _selectedMask != null
            ? WidgetMask(
                blendMode: BlendMode.srcATop,
                childSaveLayer: true,
                mask: Image.file(
                  File(widget.pickedImagePath),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                child: Image.asset(_selectedMask!),
              )
            : Image.file(
                File(widget.pickedImagePath),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
        SizedBox(height: 16),
        Text('Select a mask option:'),
        MaskOptionsList(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I think the issue might be the **String? _selectedMask;** declaration. I made it a global variable so that it is available to all the widgets. I am not sure about this though. I tried setstate to update the variable and render again but not helping. Please help in rendering the masked image immediately when i press the **MaskOptionWidget**